# Is this proof sufficient for differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\in \mathbb{Q}\\-x & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\
\end{cases}\ $$

Prove f is not differentiable at x=0.

---

### My attempted proof:

From definition of derivative:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$$

Now consider these two sequences:
$$\{{a_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty=\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\{{b_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty=\frac{1}{n+\pi}$$

Since $\{{a_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty$ consists of only rationals, we get:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(a_n)}{a_n}=\frac{a_n}{a_n}=1$$
Since $\{{b_n\}}_{n=1}^\infty$ consits of only irrationals, we get:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(b_n)}{b_n}=\frac{-b_n}{b_n}=-1$$

Therefore the limit does not exist and $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

My worry is that the sequence thing might not be correct since the function is not necessarily continuous (I don't know?).

Comment: It is correct, there is no need to worry about continuity here.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, and you don't have to worry about continuity or anything. However if you want to check for continuity you can do that using the squeeze theorem and noting that $-|x|\leq f(x) \leq |x|$.

Comment: The only reason you don't have to worry about continuity is because it is continuous at $0$. But for differentiability, you should always check for continuity first. I agree that since we answer by the negative, a discontinuity at zero won't change the result, but we have to be careful not to induce wrong beliefs to learners.